# Add the next row data into a new column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

[image]

I want to update the column `Closed_date` and `Closed_time` of `Addr= Office`. `Closed_time` as next row `Update_date` and `Update_time`.

Output should be:

[image]

I have been trying with row-id for unique identity with `case` expression:

```
Declare @maxRow int
Select @maxrow= max(ID) from Info

Declare @ID int=1
While(@ID <= @maxRow)
Begin
   Declare @Name varchar(10), @Addr varchar(10), @Update_date datetime, @Update_time varchar(10), @Closed_date datetime, @Closed_time varchar(10)

   Select @Addr = Case when Inf.Addr = 'Office' then ((Select Update_date from Info where ID=@ID+1) as @Closed_date) else Inf.Name end
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: its sql server 2008 @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `Sql Server`:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(order by ID) rn from Info)

update c1 set Closed_date = c2.Update_date,
              Closed_time = c2.Update_time 
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn - 1 and c1.Addr = 'Office' and c2.Addr <> 'Office'
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi:) It worked.I tried with Cte but i was missing condition for addr.   Thanks

Comment: Update_date and Update_time should be in ascending order and then i need to update this query.